# Import from Excel via foreach loop

Tags: excel, foreach, import, stata

I intend to `import` and work with a variety of Excel files through a `foreach` loop. The `import` itself is not working though as Stata won´t recognize `x' as a substitute for the Excel filenames.

```
local excelfiles "bb_01 bit0_2 bun comp_03 comp_c01m LLU-ck"
foreach item of local excelfiles {
import excel using "D:\...\...\...\Data\Files\`x'.XLS", sheet("DynamicReport") cellrange(A2:AI201) firstrow
keep v1 v2 v3 v4
save "D:\...\...\...\...\`x'.dta", replace
```

The error I get is `file D:\...\...\...\...\Data\Files.XLS not found`

Comment: Was the 'smart quote' (ASCII Chr(96)) used as the first tick in `x'.XLS intentional? There's another in the x.dta.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance on presenting problems that are reproducible.

Comment: Note that Excel (capital or upper case E) is undoubtedly the proprietary name. However, Stata has a bias to maximal use of lower case in its command names so that the command name (correctly rendered in the question) is `import excel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various problems here.

1. Your code is inconsistent. You declare `item` in the `foreach` statement, but refer to `x` within the loop. So, as far as Stata is concerned, local macro `x` is never defined. That is not an error in itself, but Stata replaces references to local macros that do not exist (are empty) with an empty string, with the consequence you report.
2. Your code would still not work if you replace reference to `x` with reference to `item`. See (e.g.) http://www.stata.com/manuals14/u.pdf 18.3.11 and http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0042 for warnings on following backslashes immediately with local macro references. The problem is that backslash is both an escape character and a separator within full Windows filepaths. The clash should be resolved by using forward slashes in filepaths, even within Windows.
3. The loop is never closed in the code segment you show.

I can't check your code otherwise, as your code is not reproducible. I am presuming that the triple dots `...` are not literal but replace detail that should not be crucial.

Comment: It was the backlash problem! (and as you mentioned in 1, not refering to x).

 As you have probably guessed, I am quite new to stata. so thank you for your time and patience.